# Compilation failed to complete in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I build an apk it gives an error "Compilation failed to complete"

[image]

Is there anything wrong with the module?

Comment: What version of Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin are you using? Did you try a clean build?

Comment: Gradle version 3.1.3 and yes I did clean it

Comment: 3.1.3 is very old. Upgrade to 4.10.2 and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's something wrong somewhere (haha).

Look at this line

```
Error while merging dex archives: D:\WajabatApps\Wajabat\app\build\intermediates\trans
```

This line is giving you the exception. But this is because of this line error:

```
program type already present: com.abdalltif.wajabatonline.BuildConfig
```

You get this error when you have a library module which has the same package name as the app module. Try to change the package name. This should work.

Comment: What is the library module and the app module?? And change the package name you mean the package that appears in Google play store??

Comment: "com.abdalltif.wajabatonline.BuildConfig" this is what is already present. Have you tried to change "BuildConfig" to other name?